# How to get exact element from jquery html collection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For example `$('.some-class')` returns 3 elements.

I need to get only one of them, for exampled the second.

`$('.some-class')[1]` returns HTML-version of this element, but not jQuery object.

So I need to do:

`$($('.some-class')[1])` for this purpose.

Is it the only way to do? 
Two times calling jquery selector function... may be there is better decision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.eq(index)`

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.some-class').eq(1)
```

or to select it directly:

```
$('.some-class:eq(1)')
```